# Jsondb performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, qt, nosql

Good day

I'm using QtJsonDb from http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_QtJsonDb_from_Git as a JsonDb backend NoSQL database.

It used to work very good, but now I have over 10,000 records and its becoming very very slow

I'm saving somewhat complex objects to the db

1- how fast should the db be when retrieving the details

2- is there a 3rd party application or framework where I can load the json files and test the queries on them as well and see how is the performance there

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at MongoDb, it can store data in json and it has ability to add custom indexes for quick retrieval.

Comment: Thanks, I know about MongoDb and I'm working on conversion layer for my project.
I want to know how to test the performance of this db with those large number of records if that is possible.

Comment: You could spin up a mongodb locally and just import your JSON with either mongoimport or at the application layer.